# Importing text file using read.delim

Tags: r

I have a text file which is '$' (dollar) separated and has 4.8 million rows

I have used read.delim to import the text file and the resultant file only contains 6500 rows.

a row of data looks as follows (dollar separated) on the input file (.txt):

```
65658$null$c.a.k$001F535F79875D32F49221EDF4786D02$1448928140537
```

the code I am using for import is as follows

```
EMZX <- read.delim("D:/Saeed/SPOL/Consumer_BG/EMZX.txt", header=FALSE, sep="$")
```

I have tried other options (`quote=""`) and (`numrows=4800000`) but to no avail.

If any users have had this experience and managed to identify the problem, then would very appreciate being educated.

Regards
SF

Comment: Have you tried `comment.char=""` with `quote=""` and `sep="$"`?

Comment: What is in the 6501st row of the file? Could there be junk, null bytes, etc?

Comment: yes, I used coment.char and quote= but to no avail.  However after your good advice I noticed that row 6499 and 6500 contained chinese & special chars in the 2nd column 9as shown below - but I would have thought it would just read it in as text - maybe I should try starting the read.delim on row 6501 unless there is an option to force read these special chars.  Any advice welcome.  Thanks for the earlier contribution also.

Comment: sorry forgot to show the text in row 6499 and 6500

Comment: row 6499 -> 65663$ï¼Ÿsï¼Ÿ ï¼ŸLï¼Ÿï¼Ÿï¼Ÿ4zï¼Ÿï¼Ÿ2$com.huawei.android.hwouc$0046C583BB1B0A3503C231E2FC6F0230$1449017132112
row 6500 -> 65537$ï¼Ÿ_~@Gï¼Ÿï¼Ÿ:>ï¼ŸFOUSï¼Ÿï¼Ÿï¼Ÿï¼Ÿï¼Ÿï¼Ÿï¼Ÿ0ï¼Ÿï¼Ÿ$c.a.k$0046C583BB1B0A3503C231E2FC6F0230$1449017135055